# accessing x509 certificate expiry date in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, https, x509certificate

I am trying to discover how to access the X509 expiry date information from and https url from within Xcode. 
Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW10) guide. Navigate to the section which says:"Obtaining a Policy Object and Evaluating Trust"